# Show the following...

Tags: complex-analysis

For m>0 we have the function $g_m(z) = \frac{1}{z}\prod_{l=1}^{m} \frac{z}{1-lz}$ and 
If $K_m=\sum_{l=1}^{m} Res_{z=\frac{1}{l}} g(z)$.
How do I show that $K_m=\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}$.

It seems like I will have to use the residue theorem but I am not quite sure

Answer (score 1):

The expression of $K_m$ implies that
$$ K_m = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathcal{C}} g_m(z)dz, $$
where $\mathcal{C}$ is a contour including all the simple poles $z_l=1/l$. For example we can choose the contour to be the circle $|z|=R$ with $R>1$.

We can calculate $K_m$ alternatively by letting the contour goes to infinity, because $g_m$ is analytic, i.e.,
$$ K_m = \lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R} g_m(z)dz. $$
Using the parametrization $z=R\exp(i\theta)$, this limit becomes
$$
K_m = \lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} g_m(Re^{i\theta})Re^{i \theta}d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \lim_{R\to\infty} \left[ g_m(Re^{i\theta})Re^{i \theta}\right]d\theta.
$$
Since 
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty} g_m(Re^{i\theta})Re^{i \theta}
=\lim_{R\to\infty} \prod_{l=1}^m \frac{R\exp(i\theta)}{1-lR\exp(i\theta)}
=\prod_{l=1}^m \frac{1}{(-l)}=\frac{(-1)^m}{m!},
$$
$K_m$ is $(-1)^m/m!$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decomposition in simple fractions (without computing this decomposition):
Write (taking in account that the degree of the numerator of $g_m(z)$ is $<$ to the degree of the denominator)
$$g_m(z)=\sum_{l=1}^{m}\frac{A_l}{z-1/l}$$

You want $\displaystyle K_m=\sum_{l=1}^m A_l$. We multiply by $z$, and then $z\to \infty$; then $\displaystyle \sum_{l=1}^{m}\frac{zA_l}{z-1/l}\to K_m$, and $\displaystyle zg_m(z)=\prod_{l=1}^{m}\frac{z}{1-zl}\to \frac{(-1)^m}{m!}$.